# Adding a feature in 1 or several commits

Tags: version-control, commit

Suppose I'm adding a new isolated feature 'foo' into a project. After editing source files, adding new tests for the feature foo & updating docs, I'm committing all this with a message:

```
add foo #1234
```

where #1234 is a tracking number in our bugtracker.

The question is:

Is it better to make 3 separate commits for source files, tests & docs, each marked with #1234?

Answer (score 1):

If your tests work (as in compile but return non passing), commit them first and then the rest together.

Else commit everything together as none of it makes sense without the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Answers may vary depending on which exactly VCS is used.

For SVN I would say that a feature or bug-fix should always have 1 commit on trunk. If size of changes is not trivial, a branch should be created where several commits are made, then with 1 commit to trunk you merge all changes from that branch.

With such approach you:

1. Do not pollute trunk's log with details of feature implementation.
2. Keep possibility of exploring all commits related to the feature or bug-fix.